# Cartesian Product written with Powershell

Tags: algorithm, powershell, cartesian-product

I've become very stuck trying to complete a Cartesian Product algorithm in Powershell. Using pieces of other formulas found here on stackoverflow this is what I have come up with:

```
clear

Function New-GenericDictionary([type] $keyType, [type]$valueType)
{
    $base = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2]
    $ct = $base.MakeGenericType(($keyType, $valueType))
    New-Object $ct
}

$sets = New-GenericDictionary int string
$sets[0] = "1"
$sets[1] = "0,1"
$sets[2] = "0,1"

$iterations = 1
$stringCombo = ""
foreach($key in $sets.Keys) {
    $pieces = $sets[$key].Split(",")
    $iterations = $iterations * $pieces.Length
}

for ($i = 0; $i -lt $iterations; $i++) {
    $stringCombo = ""
    foreach($key in $sets.Keys) {
        $pieces = $sets[$key].Split(",")
        $val = $pieces.Length
        $get = $i%$val
        $stringCombo = $stringCombo + " " + $pieces[$get]
    }

    Write-Host $stringCombo.Trim()
}

#output hoped for:
#1 0 0
#1 0 1
#1 1 0
#1 1 1

#output is:
#1 0 0
#1 1 1
#1 0 0
#1 1 1
```

As seen in the comments at the bottom of the code snippet the output is not quite producing the desired results. The iterations count is returning the correct value but the combinations aren't completing correctly.

In this snippet $sets[x] is fixed but in the actual script $sets dictionary items are created as part of a loop and can contain 1 to many items per iteration.

Can somebody offer a second set of eyes to show me what I've missed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improved version

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#

    CartesianProduct-Lists

#>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function CartesianProduct-Lists
{
    param
    (
        $Lists
    )

    function Make-List
    {
        param
        (
            $Head, $Tail
        )

        if ($Tail -is [Object[]])
        {
            # List already so just extend
            $Result = ,$Head + $Tail
        }
        else
        {
            # Create List
            $Result = @($Head, $Tail)
        }

        ,$Result
    }

    switch (,$Lists) {
        $Null 
        { 
            break 
        }

        # 1 List so just return it
        { $_.Count -eq 1 } 
        { 
            $_ 
        }

        # More than one list so recurse
        { $_.Count -gt 1 } 
        {  
            $Head = $_[0]
            $Index = $_.Count - 1
            $Tail = $_[1..$Index]

            $Next = CartesianProduct-Lists $Tail

            $Result = @()

            foreach ($HeadItem in $Head)
            {
                foreach ($NextItem in $Next)
                {            
                    $Result += ,(Make-List $HeadItem $NextItem)
                }
            }

            ,$Result
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need generic dictionaries for this.  A simple pair of arrays will do:

```
PS> $c1 = 0,1
PS> $c2 = 0,1
PS> foreach ($i in $c1) {
>>    foreach ($j in $c2) {
>>      "$i,$j"
>>    }
>>  }
>>
0,0
0,1
1,0
1,1
```

Comment: Ok, yes, I agree that would be better for a known number of arrays but my question is about an array of arrays. I'm trying to solve for n arrays.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a one-liner to get every unique combination. For example, with a,b,c you'd get
a, b
a, c
b, c

Here's what I came up with

```
function pairwise($list) { $i = 0; $list | % { foreach ($li in ($list | select -Skip (++$i))) { new-object PSObject -Property @{Left=$_;Right=$li} } } }
```

Answer (score 1):

My attempt worked well enough for my needs:

```
function Get-CartesianProduct {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [object[]] $List1,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [object[]] $List2)
    process {
        $List1 |
            %{
                $Item1 = $_

                $List2 |
                    %{
                        $Item2 = $_

                        @{
                            Item1 = $Item1
                            Item2 = $Item2
                        }
                    }
            }
    }
}

Get-CartesianProduct 'Apple','Rhubarb','Chocolate' 'Pie','Cake' |
    %{
        write-host $_.Item1 $_.Item2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not Beautiful but does the trick for n Lists

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#

    CartesianProduct-Lists

#>
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function CartesianProduct-Lists
{
    param
    (
        $Lists
    )

    function Make-List
    {
        param
        (
            $Head, $Tail
        )

        if ($Head -is [Object[]])
        {
            # List already so just extend
            $Result = $Head + $Tail
        }
        else
        {
            # Create List
            $Result = @($Head, $Tail)
        }

        ,$Result
    }

    # if Head..Tail 
    if (@($Lists).Count -gt 1)
    {
        $Head = $Lists[0]
        $Next = $Lists[1]

        $Result = @()
        foreach ($HeadItem in $Head)
        {
            foreach ($NextItem in $Next)
            {            
                $Result += ,(Make-List $HeadItem $NextItem)
            }
        }

        if (@($Lists).Count -gt 2)
        {
            $Index = $Lists.Count - 1
            $Tail = $Lists[2..$Index]

            $Result = ,$Result + $Tail

            $Result = CartesianProduct-Lists $Result
        }

        ,$Result
    }
}

# --------------------------------------------------------

$Lists = @(@(1),@(0,1),@(0,1))

$Result = CartesianProduct-Lists $Lists

$Result | % { $_; "" }
```

Yields

1
0
0

1
0
1

1
1
0

1
1
1